# Is it possible to see the incoming queries in mongodb to debug/trace issues?

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

I have mongo running on my macbook (OSX).

Is it possible to run some kind of a 'monitor' that will display any income requests to my mongodb?

I need to trace if I have the correct query formatting from my application.

Comment: Have you considered the database profiler: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ ?

Comment: Also look into increasing the [log verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/#db-setloglevel) level for the query component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find these tools (or utilities) useful for monitoring as well as diagnosing purposes. All the tools except `mtools` are packaged with MongoDB server (sometimes they are installed separately).

**1. Database Profiler**

The profiler stores every CRUD operation coming into the database; it is off, by default.  Having it on is quite expensive; it turns every read into a read+insert, and every write into a write+insert. ***CAUTION***: Keeping it on can quickly overpower the server with incoming operations - saturating the IO.

But, it is a very useful tool when used for a short time to find what is going on with database operations. It is recommended to be used in development environments.

The profiler setting can be accessed by using the command `db.getProfilingLevel()`. To activate the profilre use the `db.setProfilingLevel(level)` command. Verify what is captured by the profiler in the `db.system.profile` collection; you can query it like any other collection using the `find` or `aggregate` methods. The `db.system.profile` document field `op` specifies the type of database operation; e.g., for queries it is "query".

The profiler has three levels:
`0`is not capturing any info (or is turned off and default). `1` captures every query that takes over 100ms. `2` captures every query;this can be used to find the actual load that is coming in.

**2. mongoreplay**

[mongoreplay](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoreplay/index.html) is a traffic capture and replay tool for MongoDB that you can use to inspect and record commands sent to a MongoDB instance, and then replay those commands back onto another host at a later time. NOTE: Available for Linux and macOS.

**3. mongostat**

[mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) commad-line utility provides a quick overview of the status of a currently running mongod instance.

You can *view the incoming operations in real-time*. The statistics are displated, by default every second. There are various options to customize the output, the time interval, etc.

**4. mtools**

[mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) is a collection of helper scripts to parse, filter, and visualize (thru graphs) MongoDB log files.

You will find the `mlogfilter` script useful; it reduces the amount of information from MongoDB log files using various command options. For example, `mlogfilter mongod.log --operation query` filters the log by *query* operations only.

Comment: I hope something specific was useful to you.