# Is there a way to count reads/writes per collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, performance, io, nosql, performancecounter

is there a way to view the reads/writes in mongodb on a per collection-basis? I would like to see how many documents have been read and written on a specific collection.

We are currently researching the costs of some specific queries and try to find out more about if they are heavy read- and/or write-tasks.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Note on some useful tools: [Is it possible to see the incoming queries in mongodb to debug/trace issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239538/is-it-possible-to-see-the-incoming-queries-in-mongodb-to-debug-trace-issues).

Comment: You can also look at using [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) - this feature can notify for different write operations (look for Change Events).

Comment: Will have a look into the change streams. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can perform db.collection.stats() 
this will return the size and count of documents, index information and a lot of other useful information. But you want to count the number of reads and writes performed on a specific collection. For that you can use  mongostat. It captures and returns the counts of database operations by type (e.g. insert, query, update, delete, etc.). These counts report on the load distribution on the server. Read more about mongostat on their documentation. Here's the link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#bin.mongostat

Comment: First of all thanks for your input! This isn't what I've been searching for exactly. Mongotop shows only the time time spent on read/writes and mongostat just show's the performed operation. If i do run an update on 2000 dataset's it will show 2000 updates - something I already have known. I'm searching for an information how many read/writes have been spent for that particular 2000 updates (as this should differ on a collection with/without index).

Comment: If you have too many field indexed in your collection then the writes are generally slow. But the reads are faster.